# Linking Shared Object Respository in QTP

Tags: qtp

I have a doubt in linking shared object repository in qtp. There are two ways of linking object repository, one is at test level: through Resource menu and to add the repository and other way is through Action property.

If in case my Test consists of mutiple actions and if I link shared object repository through the first method then will it be linked to all the called actions?

Or my question would be what is the difference between linking shared object repository at action level and Test level? Which one is best way?what exactly happens in the both the way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better way is to have a shared OR if you are using common objects between different actions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of using shared repository is at test level, action level means we can use local repository. If you used at test level then the OR will linked to all the called actions.